# Creating a mock HttpServletRequest out of a url string?

Tags: java, mocking, servlets

I have a service that does some work on an HttpServletRequest object, specifically using the request.getParameterMap and request.getParameter to construct an object.

I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to take a provided url, in the form of a string, say

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/?param1=value1&param";
```

and easily convert it to a HttpServletRequest object so that I can test it with my unit tests? Or at least just so that request.getParameterMap and request.getParameter work correctly?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Spring has [MockHttpServletRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) in its spring-test module.

If you are using maven you may need to add the appropriate dependency to your **pom.xml**. You can find spring-test at [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test).

Answer (score 67):

Here it is how to use MockHttpServletRequest:

```
// given
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
request.setServerName("www.example.com");
request.setRequestURI("/foo");
request.setQueryString("param1=value1&param");

// when
String url = request.getRequestURL() + '?' + request.getQueryString(); // assuming there is always queryString.

// then
assertThat(url, is("http://www.example.com:80/foo?param1=value1&param"));
```

Comment: Using this MockHttpServletRequest actually does the job as I just needed a fully functional HttpServletRequest

Comment: Note that when setting the queryString the parameter Map is not updated automatically in MockHttpServletRequest. So if you use request.getParameter() in your code, you'll have to explicitly set it first the test setup even though it might seem redundant at first.

Comment: I noticed the same. Query-string and Parameters does not seem to sync up

Comment: jee api jar 6 or 8 will be needed for this.

Comment: Outdated https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html

Answer (score 40):

Simplest ways to mock an `HttpServletRequest`:

1. Create an anonymous subclass:

   ```
   HttpServletRequest mock = new HttpServletRequest ()
   {
       private final Map<String, String[]> params = /* whatever */

       public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap()
       {
           return params;
       }

       public String getParameter(String name)
       {
           String[] matches = params.get(name);
           if (matches == null || matches.length == 0) return null;
           return matches[0];
       }

       // TODO *many* methods to implement here
   };
   ```
2. Use [jMock](http://www.jmock.org/), [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), or some other general-purpose mocking framework:

   ```
   HttpServletRequest mock = context.mock(HttpServletRequest.class); // jMock
   HttpServletRequest mock2 = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class); // Mockito
   ```
3. Use HttpUnit's [ServletUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html) and don't mock the request at all.

Comment: what is the WHATEVER in the comments?

Comment: @ruby_object whatever is Map of params to be parsed in unit test. When we pass URL/?search=xyz then, this whatever will contain mapping of search for xyz.

Comment: Solution 1 won't work, as `HttpServletRequest ` can not be constructed.

Answer (score 4):

You would generally test these sorts of things in an integration test, which actually connects to a service.  To do a unit test, you should test the objects used by your servlet's doGet/doPost methods.

In general you don't want to have much code in your servlet methods, you would want to create a bean class to handle operations and pass your own objects to it and not servlet API objects.

Comment: Then again, why would you pass the opportunity to increase your test coverage (i.e. your code robustness) just because the method happen to take a certain type of parameter as input?

Comment: It depends, are you trying to unit test the servlet API or are you trying to unit test your own code?

Comment: "In general" you don't want to have any code in your servlet methods. In practice, you always will. And you will have helper-classes, utility methods, parsing, validations, model translations and sometimes even business-logic (the horror!). And since you do, you will want to unit-test them. And because of that, you'll want to mock servlet requests to create well-defined test scenarios. Mocking the servlet API is precisely the OPPOSITE of testing it. It's removing it from the test case entirely.

Answer (score 2):

for those looking for a way to mock `POST` HttpServletRequest with Json payload, the below is in Kotlin, but the key take away here is the **[DelegatingServetInputStream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/DelegatingServletInputStream.html)** when you want to mock the `request.getInputStream` from the `HttpServletRequest`

```
@Mock
private lateinit var request: HttpServletRequest

@Mock
private lateinit var response: HttpServletResponse

@Mock
private lateinit var chain: FilterChain

@InjectMocks
private lateinit var filter: ValidationFilter


@Test
fun `continue filter chain with valid json payload`() {
    val payload = """{
      "firstName":"aB",
      "middleName":"asdadsa",
      "lastName":"asdsada",
      "dob":null,
      "gender":"male"
    }""".trimMargin()

    whenever(request.requestURL).
        thenReturn(StringBuffer("/profile/personal-details"))
    whenever(request.method).
        thenReturn("PUT")
    whenever(request.inputStream).
        thenReturn(DelegatingServletInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(payload.toByteArray())))

    filter.doFilter(request, response, chain)

    verify(chain).doFilter(request, response)
}
```