# What is the best way to test method, handling HttpServletRequest object java

Tags: java, http, testing, servlets

i want to create unitest for upload file method, which accepts HttpServletRequest object . But i don't know how to create this object and pass in all the form data without executing servlet. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you describe more about your application.
Is it client-server based application.

Comment: I personally like httpUnit, another related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532/unit-testing-servlets

Comment: I'm actually try to avoid servlet testing, and test inner method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mock HttpServletRequest instance (using [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or another mocking library).

Edit: See also [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455359/creating-a-mock-httpservletrequest-out-of-a-url-string). Actually, subclassing HttpServletRequest is a way as well.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried easymock or mockito ?

Answer (score 0):

I have always used Spring Framework's classes for this, but I do Spring Framework for everything.